# Find intersection of polynomial interpolated lines

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to find the intersection of the interpolated lines in the graph below.  I have two series of datapoints.  They are as follows:

```
Red -  [0, 9.8], [11, 7], [23, 0]
Blue - [0, 0], [3, 3], [6, 10.5], [9, 21.5]
```

I'd appreciate if someone can help me get started solving this problem.

I'm assuming the first step would be to find the closest pair of points.  Then I realize solving for the intersection linearly is trivial, but the interpolation is throwing me off.

[image]

Comment: Fnd the equation for the two chuncks of lines that cross. And then solve both of them simultaneously.

Comment: It looks like the intersection you want to find is of the curve fitting to the data (not just the segments), is that right?  Is it polynomial?  If so, what order?  Do you have the equations of the curves of best fit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be fitting a quadratic to each data set.  Assuming that, you really have

Red -  [0, 9.8], [11, 7], [23, 0]

Blue - [0, 0], [3, 3], [6, 10.5], [9, 21.5]

Here it is plotted with the polynomial best fits: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xrevxk1ptp
The quadratic best fits to both are

Red: $$y_1 = -0.014295 x_1^2 - 0.097299x_1 + 9.8$$

Blue: $$ y_2 = 0.22222 x_2^2 + 0.4 x_2 -0.05 $$

The solution to this set of equations, or the point on the curve where they intersect is $(5.487, 8.836)$.  You can get that yourself by setting $y_1 = y_2$ and assuming $x_1 = x_2 = x$
$$
-0.014295 x^2 - 0.097299x + 9.8 = 0.22222 x^2 + 0.4 x -0.05
$$
and solving for $x$.  It's quadratic, but the other solution is at $x=-7.58978$, which isn't the point you want.

Comment: You're correct my x,y coords were flipped.